# How do you change this to a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have this and it does what I want it to. However how would I rewrite it as a function?

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
  if (i % 7 === 0) {
    console.log("Don't Follow your Dreams, Chase Them");
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Do I just declare the function at the beginning and instead of for do my function name? then how do I call it?

Sorry I am new to all this and wading my way through learning

Thanks

Comment: Well, that would depend on the language.

Comment: JavaScript? If so, add it as a tag Teri!

Comment: It is javascript, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You can write..

If this is javascript...

```
function myfunction()
{
   for (var i=1; i<=50; i++) 
       if (i%7=== 0) {
          console.log("Don't Follow your Dreams, Chase Them");
                     }
       else {
             console.log(i);
             }
}
```

To call your function you have to write..There are no parameters to pass

```
myfunction();
```

And if you need to pass parameters you can pass them like this..

```
function myfunction(num)
    {
       for (var i=num; i<=50; i++) 
           if (i%7=== 0) {
              console.log("Don't Follow your Dreams, Chase Them");
                         }
           else {
                 console.log(i);
                 }
    }
```

To call your function you have to write..

```
myfunction(2);
```

note:this 2 is the parameter that we are passing to the function

You can call your function from your javascript code...

Comment: Thank you so much. I was going through a tutorial and am trying to understand how to do functions but for some reason could not wrap my head around how to do that. i had all sorts of chicken scratch that was close.

Comment: ok so this is stupid, how do i test it. i am doing codeacademy and so i dont have a way to try it out

Comment: @teripastorino check the answer to know how to call your function.